# Is there a non-recipe specific, nonalcoholic, universal substitute for white wine?

Tags: substitutions, alcohol

For people on medication in which alcohol is strictly prohibited, is there a substitute that one can use in recipes that call for white wine?

Comment: How strictly prohibited? Some definitions of "strictly" would even exclude grape juice...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. White grape juice with a splash of vinegar or lemon juice in it (optional). You can typically use stock/broth or water as well, depending on the application.